# Is there a way to search for images with transparent background using Google Image Search?

Tags: google-image-search

How can I search for an image with transparent background using Google Image Search?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, Google Image search now allows you to filter results by colors, including transparent colors.

Click on **Search Tools → Colors → Transparent**

[image: Google Image Search - transparent background]