# How do you search for images with transparent backgrounds?

Tags: mobile, google-image-search

I search with Google Image search daily, and recently they have gotten rid of their 'search tools' feature with images. I wanted to know if there’s still any other way to sort images by transparent besides typing the word after everything you want to search for.

Comment: I just used “Search Tools.” Are you sure it's gone? Are you on mobile?

Comment: Yes, I am on mobile. Sorry for not specifying.

Comment: While the OP mentioned in the previous comment that they are on mobile, it's unclear what the context was then. If the question is about using the Google app for Android or iPhone and iPad, the question is off-topic in Web Applications. We need more details if the question is about using Google Images in a web browser, and confirmation that the issue was still happens.

Answer (score 3):

Search > Tools > Color > Transparent

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's possible to save some clicks, as there is "transparent" button / chip.

Comment: @Rubén The "transparent" suggestion button doesn't consistently work for this purpose—if you search for "bucket" (eg) and click the "transparent" suggestion, it includes solid-backgrounded images of transparent buckets.

Comment: @MiloP Thanks for your reply. I have seen filtering errors. I have not correlated chips / buttons with that kind of problem, but I'm sure they could happen. If you think that is something relevant, please consider editing the answer. Please bear in mind that the OP context is using Google Images on mobile according to a comment posted by them.

Comment: It might be better to consider to post a more complete answer to [Is there a way to search for images with transparent background using Google Image Search?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50415/88163)